# How to make Container wrap to text while Expanded to Row, and fit it's own width?

Tags: android, flutter, algorithm, mobile, layout

This is a weired Layout issue I recently occured.

I have tried many different ways to construct all fails.

Here is what I want:

- In a row;
- the text should expand to the row;
- the text has a Container as background, I want the container always fits the text;
- it's should expand or soft wrap but when text are not long, the contains should fits the text.

I am now trying like this:

```
 return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Container(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 8),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: PlatformTheme.getMainBkColorSection(context),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: isDarkModeOnContext(context)
                              ? const Color.fromARGB(68, 27, 27, 27)
                              : const Color.fromARGB(159, 245, 245, 245),
                          blurRadius: 9,
                          spreadRadius: 5)
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    (msg as types.SystemMessage).text,
                    style: NORMAL_S_TXT_STYLE.copyWith(
                        color: Colors.grey.shade500),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    softWrap: true,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
```

the problem is:

**to expand the text, I have to using Expanded or Flexiable in a Row, but everytime I do it, I need a container wrap text provide a bcakground, but it's always expanded to whole width**

Any one knows how to make come true?

Answer (score 0):

replace Flexible as Expanded

& remove Align & its property you’ve write after Flexible

```
child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully get your question, but to make a text fill the width/height of its parent even if the text is long, wrap it with FittedBox.